# What can come before "dankon"? Kio povas esti dirata antaŭ "dankon"?

Tags: single-word-requests

The response to "dankon" is "nedankinde", so far so good. I'm looking for a third word used to be polite, to which the response is "dankon". I can't come up with an English version. It's kind of like "here you go" (which is *jen* in Esperanto). I'd use this word when I am doing someone a favor, such as handing or giving them something.

La respondo al "dankon" estas "nedankinde. Tion mi lernis. Nun mi serĉas trian vorton uzata ĝentile, al kiu oni respondus "dankon". Mi uzus ĝin kiam mi helpas iun, ekzemple kiam mi donas ion al iu. Ĉu "jen" estas la sola ebleco? Ĉu ne estas iu ĝentilaĵo pro ĉi tiu situacio?

Answer (score 5):

Ĝentileco ofte estas afero de kutimo kaj varias de kulturo al kulturo. Ĝenerale ne estas kutimo en Esperanto por aparta vorto en tiu situacio. “Jen” ja estas bona solvo. Malpliofte mi aŭdas “bonvolu” en tiu kunteksto.

Oni povus elpensi senlimajn eblojn se oni sentas la bezonon - foje ne tute seriozajn. Jen por vi. Tre afable bonvolu akcepti. Por vi. Je via dispono. ktp.

Answer (score 2):

I think the best translation of 'here you go' is 'jen'. You could be more verbose if you like. You could say 'I did this for you' or 'this thing is for you.'

- Jen.
- Ĉi tio estas por vi.
- Mi faris ĉi tion por vi.